# Why are my ESP32's pins interconnected?

Tags: led, gpio, short-circuit, esp32

I just stumbled across this problem as I was trying to advance my terrible electrical skills :=). I built a simple circuit that gives the ESP32 a 5 V high voltage, then the ESP32 gives a transistor a high voltage to turn on an LED.

But when I gave the GPIO a 5 V high input, all of the pins received the voltage. In an attempt to troubleshoot this, I removed the ESP32 and attached it with jumpers. Then I wrote a looping program to blink the LED with pin 14. I then attached pin15, which is on the other side of the board and hooked that to another LED.

When the program started blinking the LED, the LED on pin14 blinked accordingly, but I received a steady low voltage on pin15 that made the second LED glow. I measured resistance between various pin and got around 1 MΩ. The voltages on other various pins were about 100-200 mV.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("starting");
  digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(14, LOW);
  delay(500);
}
```

The above code is what I wrote to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: I am very new to this and would appreciate any input...

Comment: I believe the ESP32 is a 3.3 volt device - applying 5 volts to a GPIO pin may damage the device.  Internal protection diodes may pull other inputs up towards 5 votls when you apply 5 volts to any input.

Comment: ^^ Pete's right.   Some micro's allow you to set a higher voltage reference for some I/O pins, but unless you know thats there and you do it, you've forward-biased the protection diodes and lit the adjacent I/O's doing so.   I've done it, and I've seen many noob EE's do it so don't feel bad that you didn't know   ;)   Now you do!

Comment: thanks. so does that mean that the board is bad now, because like i said in the question, i wrote that last program and it worked. or is my esp32 effectively dead. so is the supply input 3.3-12v@VCC? Also would the gpio output be 3.3v at "HIGH"?

Comment: Many development boards, like Arduino, Raspberry Pi, and ESP32, accept 5 volt or higher power inputs, but include voltage regulators to reduce that input voltage to the 3.3 volts or less that the circuit actually requires.  If the processor uses a 3.3 volt supply, then a logic High will be about 3.3 volts.  If your ESP32 still works, you are lucky - but it may have some damage that will show up later.

Comment: If the LED glows, that means that the voltage accross it is not "low". Do you use resitors for the LEDs? As mentioned, the ESP32 is not 5V tolerant.

Comment: Ok, I still need to experiment to see what the "damage" exactly is by writing some more stuff, but at least I'm still able to program it. I also used 5.5k resitor on that 5v input so that might have prevented excessive damage. All said I might start looking for another board online. this seems like a no brainer now, thanks, i learned a little here ;)